# Inconveniente al recibir un valor seleccionado dentro de una grilla en una página a un campo de texto en otra página en C# ASPX.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hola cordial saludo equipo necesito pedirles un favor con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta en un pequeño sitio web desarrollado en  C# Asp. Net

Mi primera página se llama Default. Aspx, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CRUDPruebas._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <div style="padding:15px; margin-right: 230px;">

       <table class="nav-justified">
           <tr>
               <td colspan="2" style="font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; color: #333333">CRUD Completo en ASP.NET con SQL </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Código_alumno"></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Obtener" Width="100px" OnClick="Button4_Click" />
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">Nombre_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">Apellido_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">Sexo_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                       <asp:ListItem>Mujer</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Hombre</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:RadioButtonList>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">Edad_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Height="16px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">Fecha_nacimiento</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Height="16px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">País_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                       <asp:ListItem>Bogotá</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Medellín</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Cali</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Barranquilla</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Riohacha</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">Correo_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">Password_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px; height: 20px">Telefono_alumno</td>
               <td style="height: 20px">
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px; height: 20px">Direccion_alumno</td>
               <td style="height: 20px">
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px; height: 20px">xxxxxx</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Height="16px" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px; height: 20px"></td>
               <td style="height: 20px">&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">&nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Insertar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Actualizar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                   <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Borrar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button3_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Esta segur@ de eliminar el registro?')" />
                   <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Cargar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button5_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Esta segur@ de eliminar el registro?')" />
                   <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" OnClick="Button6_Click" Text="Button" />
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="width: 285px">&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td colspan="2">
               <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false" Width="907px" style="margin-left: 4px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1" > 
                          <Columns>
                             
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Código_alumno" >
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<% # Bind("codalumno") %>' OnClick="lnk1_Onclick" CommandName="Select" > <%# Eval("codalumno")  %> </asp:LinkButton>  
</ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
                   
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="nombreal"  HeaderText="Nombre_alumno" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="apellal"  HeaderText="Apellido_alumno" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="sexal"  HeaderText="Sexo_alumno" />  
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="edadal"  HeaderText="Edad_alumno" />  
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="fechnalal"  HeaderText="Fecha_alumno" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="paisal"  HeaderText="Pais_alumno" />  
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="correoalu"  HeaderText="Correo_alumno" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="passwalu"  HeaderText="Password_alumno" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="telefalu"  HeaderText="Telefono_alumno" />  
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="direalu" HeaderText="Direccion_alumno" />   
               
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Visualizar">
                   <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("codalumno") %>' OnClick="lnk_Onclick" CommandName="Select">Ver modo de estado </asp:LinkButton>  
                     </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
              
                          
                          
                          </Columns>      
                  </asp:GridView>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
```

El código C# (Default.aspx.cs), es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace CRUDPruebas
{
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
       public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            
            Response.Write("Pagina cargada para el primer tiempo");
              GetEmployeeList(); 
       }
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data source=Laptop-D62FDPOD\\theserver;Initial Catalog = thebd;Trusted_Connection=true;");
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string codalumno = TextBox1.Text, nombreal = TextBox2.Text, apellal = TextBox3.Text, sexal = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue, paisal = DropDownList1.SelectedValue, correoalu = TextBox6.Text, passwalu = TextBox7.Text, telefalu = TextBox8.Text, direalu = TextBox9.Text;
            double edadal = double.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
            DateTime fechnalal = DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
            connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into alumnos values ('" + codalumno + "', '" + nombreal + "','" + apellal + "', '" + sexal + "',  '" + edadal + "','" + fechnalal + "', '" + paisal + "','" + correoalu + "', '" + passwalu + "','" + telefalu + "','" + direalu + "')", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Almacenado satisfactoriamente');", true);
            GetEmployeeList();
  }
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string codalumno = TextBox1.Text, nombreal = TextBox2.Text, apellal = TextBox3.Text, sexal = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue, paisal = DropDownList1.SelectedValue, correoalu = TextBox6.Text, passwalu = TextBox7.Text, telefalu = TextBox8.Text, direalu = TextBox9.Text;
            double edadal = double.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
            DateTime fechnalal = DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
            connection.Open();
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Update alumnos set  codalumno='" + codalumno + "',nombreal='" + nombreal + "',apellal='" + apellal + "',sexal= '" + sexal + "',edadal= '" + edadal + "',fechnalal= '" + fechnalal + "',paisal='" + paisal + "',correoalu='" + correoalu + "',passwalu= '" + passwalu + "',telefalu='" + telefalu + "',direalu='" + direalu + "' where codalumno='" + int.Parse(codalumno) + "'", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Actualizado satisfactoriamente');", true);
            GetEmployeeList();
}
public void GetEmployeeList()
        {
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from alumnos", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dt); 
                sd.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;

                GridView1.DataBind();
}
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
}

  public void lnk1_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
           {
string codalumno = ((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);  //Aquí es en donde se captura el valor obtenido dando clic en el enlace  
         Response.Redirect("NotasAlumnos.aspx?codalumno1=" + codalumno,false);
}
Y el código aspx del formulario que recibe el valor (NotasAlumnos.aspx), es el siguiente:
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CRUDPruebas._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <div style="padding:15px">

 <table class="nav-justified" style="width: 81%">
      <tr>
               <td colspan="2" style="font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; color: #333333">Registro de notas por alumno </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td style="width: 51px">&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td style="width: 51px">Codigo_alumno</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="codalumno1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px" Enabled="False" BackColor="#F2F0E1"></asp:TextBox>  <!—Cuadro de texto el cual debe de recibir el código del alumno (Codigo_alumno) --!>
               </td>
           </tr>


     
           <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="height: 20px; width: 51px;">Nota</td>
               <td style="height: 20px">
                   <asp:TextBox ID="nota2" runat="server" Width="247px"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
           </tr>

            <tr>
               <td style="width: 51px">&nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="ButtonA" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Insertar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                   <asp:Button ID="ButtonB" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Actualizar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                   <asp:Button ID="ButtonC" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Borrar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button3_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Esta segur@ de eliminar el registro?')" />
                   <asp:Button ID="ButtonD" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Text="Cargar" Width="100px" OnClick="Button5_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Esta segur@ de eliminar el registro?')" />
               </td>
           </tr>
       <tr>
               <td class="modal-lg" style="height: 20px; width: 51px;">&nbsp;</td>
               <td style="height: 20px">&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
       
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
         <asp:GridView ID="GridViewN" runat="server" Width="907px" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
          
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="codalumno" headertext="Codigo_alumno"   />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="nota"  HeaderText="Nota" />
                       <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("codalumno") %>' OnClick="lnk_Onclick">Ver modo de estado </asp:LinkButton>
                     </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
                      
             </Columns>      
                  </asp:GridView>
     </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
      <div style = "text-align: center; width: 1010px;">
      
      <a href="" OnClick="lnkVolver_Click">Hipervinculo piloto</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

El código NotasAlumnos.aspx.cs, es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CRUDPruebas
{
    public partial class NotasAlumnos : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
/* Aquí el segmento de código para recibir el valor seleccionado en el campo codalumno del formulario Default.aspx */  
 if (Request.QueryString["codalumno1"] != null) //  / 
            {

                string codal= Request.QueryString["codalumno1"];
                codalumno1.Text = codal;
            }
                else
            {
                    codalumno1.Text = "Error, valor no seleccionado";
            }
   }
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data source=Laptop-D62FDPOD\\the server Initial Catalog = theBd ;Trusted_Connection=true;");
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string codalumno = codalumno1.Text, nota1 = nota.Text;
           
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into notas values ('" + codalumno + "', '" + nota1 + "')", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Almacenado satisfactoriamente');", true);
            GetEmployeeList();
        }
void GetEmployeeList()
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from notas", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sd.Fill(dt);
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  DropDownList dropDownList1 = DropDownList1;
            string codalumno = codalumno1.Text, nota1 = nota.Text;

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Update notas set codalumno='" + codalumno + "',nota='" + nota + "' where codalumno='" + codalumno + "')", connection);
            connection.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Actualizado satisfactoriamente');", true);
            GetEmployeeList();

        }
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string codalumno = codalumno1.Text;
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Delete notas where codalumno='" + codalumno + "')", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Borrado satisfactoriamente');", true);
            GetEmployeeList();
        }
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string codalumno = codalumno1.Text;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from notas where codalumno='" + codalumno + "'", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sd.Fill(dt);
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetEmployeeList();
        }
        protected void lnkVolver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

        }
protected void lnk_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int codalumno = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);

            SqlCommand sqlDa = new SqlCommand("Select * from alumnos where codalumno='" + codalumno + "'", connection); //ContactViewByID
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlDa);

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sd.Fill(dtbl);

            codalumno1.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["codalumno"].ToString();
            nota.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["nota"].ToString();


            Button2.Text = "Actualizar";
            Button3.Enabled = true;

         
        }
    }
}
```

FRGFRGT GTGTGTGHT HYHYHYHY ESFRFEWFERG GTRHYTHYTH HUTJUYJUYJUY GYHRHYNYTN HYYTHTYHT HYHNHGBGFBGF BYHYTBYTNYT HYTJNJTNTH JUYKUYNHGNGJH HYTJGYNHGNHG HGFJHGHGNHG JJFHNFGNV
Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar
Atentamente
Hernán Martínez

Comment: Tuviste que agregar texto de nada, porque pusiste un monton de codigo, pero en ningun lugar, explicaste tu problema... como podemos saber de que hablas solo con codigo???

Comment: Hola señor gbianchi me alegra saber una vez mas de ti, el problema esta en que al seleccionar  con un clic un registro de la grilla de la pagina de origen, es decir un registro del codigo_del_alumno que esta dentro de una grilla me lo muestra en la Url pero no en el campo de texto de la hoja de destino, saludos y muchas gracias por a observación disculpa las molestias.